# Proving the derivative of sin(x)

Tags: calculus, analysis

I was able to manipulate this identity: $$\sin{\left(x+\alpha\right)}-\sin{\left(x\right)}=2\sin{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\cos{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\alpha\right)}$$ to be $$=\cos{\left(x+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\cdot\frac{\sin{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}}{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$$

Using the limit definition of the derivative, it is found that the derivative of this is $\cos(x)$. How does this prove the derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$?

Comment: Now send $\alpha \to 0$ and exploit the (geometrically provable) property $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$.

Comment: @ian I did that. I can show that the last equation written becomes cos(x) after taking the limit. But how does this prove the derivative of sin? where is sine here?

Comment: @Burt Actually you need to divide the first equation by $\alpha$. The derivative of a function is $\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{f(x+\alpha) - f(x)}{\alpha}$, here you have sine

Answer (score 3):

You've done most of the hard work

The definition of the derivative of a function at a point $x $ is

$$f'(x) = \lim_{\alpha\to 0} \frac{f(x+\alpha) - f(x)}{\alpha}$$

Now, if you use your calculation and put it in the numerator, and use the fact that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

You should get the proof